# Unable to run the contextual add-in provided by outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am following the example from this link https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Contextual-Regex

Note: I am running the application locally.

So, on uploading the manifest.xml file on the outlook it highlights the regex text, but clicking it, doesn’t work. Seems like `index.js` is working.

getting this error below:

```
logAddinUsage.ts:105 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.get_Type is not a function
    at logAddinUsage.ts:105
    at d (logAddinUsage.ts:30)
    at H.notifyHostError (OsfControlAdapter.ts:164)
    at H.notifyHostActions.<computed> (OsfControlAdapter.ts:79)
    at u.ContextActivationManager.H.notifyHost (OsfControlAdapter.ts:158)
    at u.ContextActivationManager.displayNotification (osfruntime.js:19)
    at u.OsfControl._showActivationError (osfruntime.js:19)
    at osfruntime.js:19
    at osfruntime.js:19
```

Comment: Have you tried filing an issue in the `OfficeJS` repo on GitHub?

Comment: raised now https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2319

Answer (score 0):

**This has been considered a bug and the current status is `fix-pending`.**

For more follow the issue raised https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2319